# Finite index normal subgroup in a normalised union of two groups.

Tags: gr.group-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Existence of simultaneously normal finite index subgroups](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34592/existence-of-simultaneously-normal-finite-index-subgroups)

$G$ is a group, $A$ and $B$ are two subgroups of $G$. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $A\cap B$ which is of finite index in both $A$ and $B$. Does $H$ has a subgroup of finite index which is normal in both $A$ and $B$?

**Edit :** In view of the negative answer pointed below, let me add the additional requirement that the union $A\cup B$ be normalised by $G$.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34592/existence-of-simultaneously-normal-finite-index-subgroups

Comment: @Gjergji Zaimi Could this question be opened again, or should I open a new question?