# Finite indexed simultaneously normal subgroup in a normal union of two groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

As this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81146/finite-index-normal-subgroup-in-a-normalised-union-of-two-groups-closed) was closed as a duplicate of [Existence of simultaneously normal finite index subgroups](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34592/existence-of-simultaneously-normal-finite-index-subgroups), I am opening a modified version here.

$G$ is a group, $A$ and $B$ are two subgroups of $G$. Suppose that $A∩B$ has finite index in both $A$ and $B$. It has been shown [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34592/existence-of-simultaneously-normal-finite-index-subgroups) that $A\cap B$ need not have a subgroup of finite index which is normal in both $A$ and $B$.

**Question** : If the set $A\cup B$ is normalised by $G$, does $A\cap B$ has a subgroup of finite index which is normal in both $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fact is true. Here is the proof that if $A\cup B$ is normal in $G$, then $A\cap B$ is normal in $G$ or $A^g$ is inside $B$ for some $g$. Suppose that $A^g$ is not inside $B$ for any $g$. If $A\cup B$ is normal in $G$, then $A$ and $B$ are normalized by an index at most 2 subgroup $G_1$ of $G$. Indeed, for every $g\in G$, we have $A^g$ is a union of two subgroups $A^g\cap A$ and $A^g\cap B$. That can happen only if $A^g=A$ or $A^g=B$, same for $B$. 
Now if $G_1=G$, there is nothing to prove. If $G_1$ is of index 2, then there exists an element $g$ with $A^g=B$, $B^g=A$ and $G=\langle G_1, g\rangle$. Therefore $A\cap B$ is normal in $G$. In particular, it is normal in $A$ and $B$. Now suppose that $A^g$ is inside $B$ for some $g$. Notice that for every $h\in G$ either $A^h=A$ or $A^h\subseteq  B$ and similarly either $B^h=B$ or $B^h\subseteq A$. If $A^h\subseteq B$ and $B^h \subseteq A$ then $(A\cap B)^h=A\cap B$. Therefore the normalizer $C$ of $A\cap B$ together with the normalizer $D$ of $B$ gives the whole $G$. This again implies that either $C=G$ and $A\cap B$ is normal in $G$ or $D=G$, and $B$ is normal in $G$. Thus the only case left is when $A^g\subseteq B$ for some $g$ and $B$ is normal in $G$. In that case $A\subseteq B^{g^{-1}}=B$, so $A\cap B=A$ and since it must be of finite index in $B$ by assumption, we conclude that $A=A\cap B$ has a normal subgroup of finite index both in $A$ and in $B$.

Comment: @Mark Sapir : Thanks ! You are proving even more : if some group K normalises $A\cup B$, then it normalises $A\cap B$, and your key point is that a union of two distinct subgroups is not a group.

Comment: @Drike: Reading Mark's answer carefully also shows that the correct spelling is "normalize" (not "normalise"). 

Comment: @Todd: perhaps @Drike is a native English speaker (as opposed to a native, or otherwise, American speaker)? Google "normalize" and you will be enlightened.

Comment: I am not a native English speaker, so my spelling cannot be trusted. Google gives 10 mil links for "normalize" and 3 mil links for "normalise". I guess this makes both versions possible. 

Comment: I think Drike (deleted comment) and the others are right: "normalize" is American English and "normalise" British English. More examples can be found on http://www.spelling.org/free/instructional/british_vs_american_spelling.htm. An example in mathematical context is the announcement http://www.talks.cam.ac.uk/talk/index/34171 
where "generalise" appears. Sorry, if my comment led to confusion. 

Comment: @Ashot: Indeed, I missed the case when $A^g$ is inside $B$ (so $A^g=A^g\cap B$). But that case is even easier. 

Comment: @Todd, @Igor - Actually '-ize' and '-ise' are both acceptable in British English; '-ize' is often referred to as the 'Oxford spelling' (see wikipedia). I think the key lesson here is not to try to correct others' spelling unless you actually have some idea about spelling yourself (and probably best not even then).